# How do I add to $page_top in html.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I wanted to add a piece of HTML at the top of all pages, right after `<body>`. In the #drupal IRC channel I got the recommendation to override `html.tpl.php` in the theme. That works fine. But isn't there some useful hook that I could use, so I don't have to copy `html.tpl.php` and just add a few lines?

I tried to modify `$variables['page']['page_top']` in `THEME_preprocess_page()` and `THEME_preprocess_html()` but upon debugging `$page_top` in `html.tpl.php`, the changes had been discarded.

How do I do it by hook? And which way is to prefer?

Comment: Hook will probably use more time than a simple, static change to one tpl file. And why copy it? Most themes needs to have it anyway, already, so all you need is to alter it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how the Drupal core toolbar module does this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 *
 * Add admin toolbar to the page_top region automatically.
 */
function toolbar_page_build(&$page) {
  $page['page_top']['toolbar'] = array(
    '#pre_render' => array('toolbar_pre_render'),
    '#access' => user_access('access toolbar'),
    'toolbar_drawer' => array(),
  );
}
```

This is probably the most correct way of adding something to the page top as you can comfortably use render arrays.

Answer (score 0):

$page_top is rendered in [template_process_html()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7). You should be able to override that function to add material before it is rendered and assigned to $variable

Comment: I interpreted this as implementing THEME_process_html(), but when I did that I had rendered HTML to deal with. That is actually fine in my case because I can just prepend my HTML to `$variables['page_top']`. But I'm still wondering where the opportunity is to modify the render array (and that is what your answer really seems to be about - am I misunderstanding it?).

Comment: As per the link I provided, the function does the following: $variables['page_top'] = drupal_render($variables['page']['page_top']); where the array is rendered. It also states at the very top of the page, "To customize these variables, call drupal_render() on elements in $variables['page'] during THEME_preprocess_page()"

Answer (score 0):

You can add region page_top in your_theme.info file, see reference [Writing theme .info files](https://www.drupal.org/node/171205#regions)
The other way is to change html.tpl.php file in your theme, but the first way is better.